# How can I make my google fonts render properly in chrome (windows xp)

Tags: website-design, browser, google

This is the [**SITE**](http://kiljano.se) and it looks great in firefox on both windows XP and mac OS10.6. But with chrome on my XP it looks wierd. All the texts are jagged and pixlated sort of. I have tried with and without clear type turned on and of, without any difference I have also tried a css tweak: -webkit-text-stroke
but without luck. Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you

The font is [Cuprum](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Cuprum), and here's a [screenshot of the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8sexph0ofaygxu/screendump_chrome.JPG).

Comment: aksello - some web font providers offer previews of their fonts on different operating system/browser combinations. Look for the same fonts you're using on typekit, fonts.com etc and see if the previews match what you're seeing. @Farray did you not notice that the asker links to the site in question? "This is the SITE [link]" It would be helpful if they saved people time and effort by quoting the font used and providing screenshots in the question, but it's their first post, you can be more constructive in your feedback.

Comment: All the information needed to answer the question is available, and figuring out how to deal with surprising web font rendering issues is a common, real problem designers often face. What works for one font often works for others. I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see any difference between Chrome and Firefox. I made screenshots and a side by side comparison. If anything I'm surprised as how identical both browsers render  the text. 
Each letter is constructed with the same pixel position. colors are slightly different, but that's it.

Do you have any screenshots that show the jagged text?

Win 7 x64 Firefox 11 & Chrome 19

Comment: Maby its better on win7. I only have XP to try. It looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8sexph0ofaygxu/screendump_chrome.JPG

Comment: Win7 renders fonts completely different compared to XP, so this doesn't answer the question. Please see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/265/font-face-loaded-on-windows-look-really-bad-which-fonts-are-you-using-that-rend for an explanation on font rendering